# How to do horizontal crawling with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to do horizontal crawling with scrapy. With an Xpath,I am getting the link that is going to lead me to the next page. 
Then I am trying to concatenate this link to the url of the site doing with following:

```
Join()([response.url, next_page])
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments
```

So I convert to a string the response of the request that gets me the link to the next page:

```
Join()([response.url, str(next_page)])
```

However, when I repeat the same concatenation process, the response of the request to get the link of the next page is concatenated with square brackets, not enabling me to start the horizonthal crawling:

```
"https://www.nyhabitat.com/new-york-apartment/roommate-share ['roommate-share-2']"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `next_page` is an *array*. Try to get it using `.extract_first()` instead of `.extract()` or `.get()` instead of `.getall()`.
Also you need to use `response.urljoin(next_page)` to get target URL or even:

```
yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.your_callback)
```